# Assign var as a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a var named as sliceText which contains a text which is collected whenever user hover over the section of a visualforce chart. I'm trying to increase the size of this text with a value which gets calculated at run time and newSize var hold the same. But using jquery following syntax is not working and I'm not able change the font size.

```
var sliceText = j$(this).text();
j$(sliceText).css('font-size', newSize);
```

How can I assign a var as a selector using jquery? I want following solution work for me but its NOT when I tried to!! https://docs.acquia.com/articles/increase-text-size-jquery

Comment: `sliceText ` will be what? An Id or a class?

Comment: var sliceText = j$(this).text(); It holds the text value from a visualforce chart this is collected whenever user hovers particular section from pie chart

Comment: Yeah but what is the value present in `sliceText`?

Comment: Imagine I have a pie chart, which contains 6 months data and is differentiated with different color and each section have month name in it as Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun. sliceText var holds the value as Jan whenever user mouseover that particular part/slice of pie chart. It is not an id or class.

Comment: you cant directly apply any CSS property on text/string.

Comment: Exactly! and my req want me to do the same. So any workaround is available as if I put j$(this) instead of j$(this).text() then it works but in effect font size increase for all 6 month values irrespective of where mouse hovers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply css to the DOM object containing the text no the text

```
j$('path, tspan').mouseover(function(e) {
j$(this).children().css('font-size', 15);//reset to default size font
j$(e.target).css('font-size', newSize); 
});
```

Comment: j$(this) gives me complete expression as JanFebMarAprMayJun and j$(this).text() gives me Jan if I'm pointing or hovering over Jan area from a pie chart. So I want j$(this).text() and NOT j$(this) as I want to change the font size of Jan as I'm pointing to Jan area.

Comment: here you go: <script type="text/javascript"> function funtest() {var oldSize = parseFloat(j$('text').css('font-size')); var newSize = oldSize * 2; j$('path, tspan').mouseover(function() {var sliceText = j$(this).text(); j$(sliceText).css('font-size', newSize); }); } </script>

Comment: This works for me! I will update for issues, if any! Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned whether the dom is an id or a class

```
    var sliceText = j$(this).text();
    j$("#"+sliceText).css('font-size', newSize); --- if the dom element is an id

    j$("."+sliceText).css('font-size', newSize);  --- if the dom element is  a class
```

Comment: Umm...help me how can I define dom element as an id or a class. How can I make your solution work in my case? <script type="text/javascript"> function funtest() {var oldSize = parseFloat(j$('text').css('font-size')); var newSize = oldSize * 2; j$('path, tspan').mouseover(function() {var sliceText = j$(this).text(); j$(sliceText).css('font-size', newSize); }); } </script>

Comment: @Pooja please let me know what sliceText contained. element Id or CSS class

Comment: it is just a var and value gets assigned within mouseover funation as I want Jan as a value get stored in sLiceText var and not JanFebMarAprmayJun. All these values are on visualforce pie chart. As asked by you correctly "what sliceText contained element Id or CSS class"; question to you is how can I define this element as Id or class if I want to?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newSize = '30px';

var originalSize = '14px';

$("span").hover(function(){
        $(this).css('font-size', newSize); 
        }, function(){
        $(this).css('font-size', originalSize); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> Jan </span><br/>

<span>Feb</span><br/>

<span>March</span>
```

Comment: In your example you have span. So this will work! Pasting my code for ready reference - <script type="text/javascript"> function funtest() {var oldSize = parseFloat(j$('text').css('font-size')); var newSize = oldSize * 2; j$('path, tspan').mouseover(function() {var sliceText = j$(this).text(); j$(sliceText).css('font-size', newSize); }); } </script>

Comment: Try this : <script type="text/javascript">
    function funtest() {
        var oldSize = parseFloat(j$('text').css('font-size'));
        var newSize = oldSize * 2;
        j$('path, tspan').mouseover(function() {
            //var sliceText = j$(this).text();
            j$(this).css('font-size', newSize);
        });
    }
</script>

Comment: I tried this but  j$(this) will change the font size irrespective of where mouse hovers on visualforce chart. My req. is to on visualforce pie chart, if I'm hovering over Jan then only font size Jan should get increased!

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to change the font size of hover element
so  try this one

```
function funtest()
{
    var oldSize = parseFloat(j$('text').css('font-size'));
    var newSize = oldSize * 2;
    j$('path, tspan').mouseover(function () {
        j$(this).css('font-size', newSize);
    });
}
```

Comment: My visualforce chart contains 6 values as Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun! j$(this).css('font-size', newSize); will incerase the font size but across all values. I want to change the font size where mouse hover over like Jan as my mouse is in this section rest all monthwise section text should remain intact.

Comment: please execute this code "console.log(j$(this).prop('tagName')) " within mouseover function  and let me know the output

Comment: Visualforce Chart: Generate schema from result,SfdcCore.js:385 Visualforce Chart: Data row count for chart 'jid0jid3': 6, VFChart.js:2274 Visualforce Chart:Data,https://login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found),3vfchartsample:33 path,3vfchartsample:33 tspan
6vfchartsample:33 path,VFChart.js:411 'SVGElement.offsetParent' is deprecated and will be removed in M50, around April 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5724912467574784 for more details.,62vfchartsample?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1:33 path